# Why printout is not null?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, null

Why this happened?

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("aaa");
String s = list.get(0);
list.remove(0);
System.out.println(s);
```

Console says: `aaa`

Can somebody explain it for me? I thought console should be `null`, should it be?

Comment: Of course it shouldn't. You assigned "aaa" to `s` before you removed it from the list. So naturally, it's still there...

Comment: There should be another closure reason.  Too embarrassing.  :-)

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in your debugger and you will be able to see what each line does.

Comment: Did you mean to print `list` not `s`?

Answer (score 5):

No, because you stored the value from list in a `s`. So the reference to the `"aaa"` was in both list and `s`, after you removed it from list, `s` has still reference to it.

Comment: thanks to all of you , i thought the obj shound be remove from memory,when the operation list.remove(0) is done.

Answer (score 1):

No. It works as expected. `S` still holds a reference to `"aaa"`. You only changed the list, not `S`.

Comment: `S` still holds reference to "aaa" instance

Answer (score 1):

`String s = list.get(0);`

You saved the reference to `s`, then printed the value of it. What's the problem?

[List#remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29) changes the list, not the variable `s`, `s` still have reference to the `"aaa"`.

You probably want to switch the order:

```
list.remove(0);
String s = list.get(0);
```

Comment: Your answer is right, but switching the order in `THIS` case, would throw `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`!

Comment: Yes I know, I was reffering a situation in which there are at least 2 elements

Answer (score 1):

Let me put that into a story:

You write yourself a note saying "aaa" (just writing `"aaa"` actualy defines a new string), to make sure you never forget that. At the same time you decide that it might be a good idea to pin another note to your fridge telling you where you put your note from earlier (`list.add(...)`).

At some point you see this on your fridge and decide to track down your note (`list.get(0)`). Then you realize that you don't really need the reminder any more, because you hold the note in your hand, so you remove that from your fridge (`list.remove(0)`). What do you still hold in your hand?

I guess it will be much clearer, when you write out exactly what happens in your code, without ommitting any steps:

```
String note = "aaa";
List<String> fridge = new ArrayList<String>();
fridge.add(note);
note = null; // forget about the note, the fridge will remember

String someNote = list.get(0);
fridge.remove(0); // now the fridge forgets, but you still have the note
System.out.println(someNote);
```